# Is there any way to programmatically clear Hazelcast Cache Statistics?

Tags: hazelcast, spring-cache

The scenario is to clear the stats whenever the cache is cleared.

Request some examples in Java/Spring.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To get Near Cache statistics, use the getNearCacheStats() method from the LocalMapStats object.. -> clear..  Here's a [Reference on Near Cache Statistics](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-dev/manual/html-single/index.html#near-cache-statistics) and [Management](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-dev/manual/html-single/index.html#management)

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's no way to clear the statistics. One thing that I can suggest it, instead of clearing the cache, you destroy it. This way all stats related to that dist. cache is also destroyed. Once you access it again, it's created as a new object & clean stats.